# Angular JS form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

My form validation is not working on clicking of submit button. I have properly added controller in HTMl.Any lead will be appreciated.Thanks in advance :)

```
 <form id="formbody"  ng-submit="submit(user)" name="form" novalidate="">

    <div class="formtext" >

    <div class="has-header">
      <ion-label class="labelstyle" > Select Service  </ion-label>
      <input  ng-click="goToPage()" name="selectsrve" type="text" class="formtext1 inputimg"  ng-model="user.firstname" placeholder=" Select from list" required="">
      <!-- <img   src="img/icon-arrow-gray.png"></img> -->
      </input>
      <span ng-show="user.firstname.$dirty && users.firstname.$error.required">Please select the Service</span>
    </div>
     <div style="padding-left: 275px;">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
     <!--  <div  type="button" id="btn" style="color: red;" >Submit</div> -->
    </div>
    </div>
        </form>


.controller('ExampleController',function($scope,$location,$scope, $stateParams){
     $scope.singleSelect='';

     $scope.goToPage=function(){
        console.log("selectservice");
        $location.path("/selectservice");
     }

     $scope.submit = function(){
    // Set the 'submitted' flag to true
    alert("In the submit button");
    $scope.submit=function(user){
        alert("user"+user.firstName);
    };

  }

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$scope.submit` function should be like this. Remove the other `$scope.submit` function inside of it. And why do you have a `ng-click` inside your input? and it redirect when you click your input

```
$scope.submit = function(user){

     alert("user"+user.firstName);
}
```

Comment: It is because i have to navigate to another page by clicking on that i/p and from there i have to select the services. And if it is empty then error should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in your code

in your span instead of `user.firstname.$dirty && users.firstname.$error.required` you should use form name and input field name `form.$submitted && form.selectsrve.$invalid && form.selectsrve.$error.required`

you can also use condition in your `ng-submit` to submit form only if it is valid `ng-submit="form.$valid && submit(form)"`

and in your controller use scope variable to get user

```
$scope.submit=function(){
        alert("user "+$scope.user.firstname);
    };
```

Please have a look at this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N9onwbzFDIBC7KqPxtOw?p=preview)